# Prevent scrolling jquery script from running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I'm new to jquery and have put together the following code to make a DIV appear after a set scroll-down amount. If scrolling back up, the DIV disappears. Optionally, once the DIV has appeared, there is a link to close it. This all works as intended, apart from that I only want the script to run once. At the moment if I scroll back up, the yellow box appears again. How can I ensure the box stays closed? As another option, could I integrate cookies or localStorage?

Many thanks! Russ.

**Javascript:**

```
$(function () {
    var target = $(".box");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
        target.hide();
    }
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos > 30) {
            target.stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            target.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
    $('a.close').click(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle link to my code: [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/RussBass/AbwXu/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove event scroll from window and for localStorage do something like that:

```
$(function () {
    var target = $(".box");
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 30) {
        target.hide();
    }
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos > 30) {
            target.stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            target.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
        if(localStorage['noNotification'] == 'true'){
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }
    });
    $('a.close').click(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideUp();
        $(window).off('scroll');
        localStorage['noNotification'] = 'true';
        return false;
    });
```

});

Comment: Worked a treat! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know of a way I could either use a cookie or localStorage so that if, in the same browser session, this page is revisited, the DIV does not appear again?

Comment: the div will not appear again i used localStorage for that.

Comment: The above example works very well. I just tidied up the fade animation by using 'scroll' rather than 'stop':

`$(window).scroll(function () {
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (pos > 30) {
            target.scroll(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        } else {
            target.scroll(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
        }
        if(localStorage['noNotification'] == 'true'){
            $(window).off('scroll');
        }`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the class to ensure the box stays enclosed with `removeClass()`. Or directly `$(".box").remove()` after your animation.
You can store this choice with cookie but if the client deletes his cookies, it's lost.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/AbwXu/4/

```
var notdisplayed=true;
$(function(){ 
    var target = $(".box");
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 30){
      target.hide();
    }
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(pos > 30  && notdisplayed){
            target.stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');

        } else {
            target.stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
            notdisplayed=false;
        }
    });
    $('a.close').click(function() {
        $($(this).attr('href')).slideUp();
        notdisplayed=false;
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Hi there,Thanks for such a quick answer! Unfortunately, I don't see the yellow DIV when I scroll down in your version.

Comment: Please check again i can see it are you sure you cant see? Can anyone else verify?